# SMS not delivered while sending it through Nexmo

Tags: vonage

I am trying to send SMS from the URL https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/xml?api_key=xxxxxx&api_secret=xxxxxxx&from=+15xxxxx23&to=+9xxxxxxx5&text="Hello Text Msg from nexmo". I am getting the response with the status as "OK" and money has been debited from the account. But SMS is not sent to the number. Can you please help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information? Did you just sign up? New accounts are usually in "demo mode" until you top up with credit but this should allow you to send SMSes to registered test numbers (but possibly not between different countries - I'm guessing from the hidden dialling codes that this might be the case). There are also different restrictions in different geographies: more details here https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/sections/200622473-Country-Specific-Features-and-Restrictions

Comment: I should also add that there are more general troubleshooting tips here https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204016013-How-can-I-troubleshoot-SMS-delivery- - check the status response, make sure you're sending from and to registered numbers if you're in demo mode ... hope this helps!

Comment: @LornaMitchell - "To" Number is an India Number and on further analysis, it has been registered to "Do not disturb". I tried with the same parameters for another number and it works fine. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `+` before the phone numbers.

"Formatting
Within the Vonage Voice API all numbers are in E.164 format. This means that numbers:

Omit both a leading + and the international access code such as 00 or 001.
Contain no special characters, such as a space, () or -
For example, a US number would have the format 14155550101. A UK number would have the format 447700900123.

If you are unsure how to format the number the Number Insight API can be used to find correct information about a number."

Source: [Numbers Documentation the Vonage Website](https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/guides/numbers).